# JavaScript namespace and IE8, null or not an object error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, javascript-namespaces

I am working on an application which was supposed to be compatible with modern browsers but now we have a requirement that it should support older browsers like IE8, IE9..

I have followed namespace pattern while developing an app. Like the followings..

`var myApp = myApp || {};`

`myApp.Globals = {}`

I have referred to Addy Osmani's blog for the same..

It works well on IE10+ but for IE8 and IE9 the variables are undefined.

e.g. if I console log these namespaces it returns undefined with this error :

`myApp.Globals is null or not an object`

Is there any way to fix them in IE8 and IE9?

Comment: That should work, do you have a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: IE9 is the main browser that I have to support and I can confirm that this works

Comment: I will try to replicate my code in jsfiddle, will work on that now